# How to refer to a string as the name of a list?

Tags: python, string, list, numpy

Suppose there are 3 lists:

```py
l_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l_2 = ['d', 'e', 'f']
l_index = ['l_1', 'l_2']
```

So `l_index` contains names of 2 other lists. I want first to select a list by randomness, for which I can use:

```py
import random
selected_list = random.choice(l_index)
```

Then I need to select an element in that list, also by randomness. However this doesn't work:

```py
selected_element = random.choice(selected_list)
```

It's because `selected_list` is treated as a string. How can I make python refer to it as a list instead?

Comment: Why not just use the actual `l_1` variable instead of a string, and get a random number based off of the length of lists, then access the list with this random index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could contain the two lists themselves in another list, and then make a random selection from 0 to the number of lists minus one.

```sql
import random

l_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l_2 = ['d', 'e', 'f']
lists = [l_1, l_2]
idx = random.randint(0, len(lists) - 1)
random_list = lists[idx]
selected_element = random.choice(random_list)
print(selected_element)  # prints from both lists over time
```

Comment: Why the clumsy way via index, when they and you already know and use choice?

Comment: Even with randint instead of randrange...

Comment: I am not a Python expert.  I am just fairly good at convincing people that I am one!

Answer (score 1):

You should have a list of the variables as suggested in the other answer, but if you have to use strings to get the lists use `locals()` to get a `dict` with the variables names as `keys`

```
selected_list = random.choice(l_index)
random.choice(locals()[selected_list])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
from random import choice

l_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l_2 = ['d', 'e', 'f']
l_index = [l_1, l_2] # note use of variable names - not strings
    
print(choice(choice(l_index)))
```

Answer (score 0):

we can avoid using a variable that holds the list names.

```
from random import choice
l_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l_2 = ['d', 'e', 'f']
print(choice(l_1 + l_2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
l_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l_2 = ['d', 'e', 'f']
l_index = [l_1, l_2]
selected_list = random.choice(l_index)
selected_element = random.choice(selected_list)
print(selected_element)
```

Your code was totally fine but in `l_index` you used its element as string remove those quotes

WRONG ONE:

```
l_index = ['l_1', 'l_2']
```

RIGHT ONE:

```
l_index = [l_1, l_2]
```

else everything will be same